# how assert function return the file name and code line upon failure

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to add an API call to my `C`/`C++` application. In addition to its operation, it also should return the name of file and the line of code that it has been called from.

I figured out the `assert(condition)` function of `C` does the same. Once the `condition` is false, `assert` breaks the execution and reports the file name and line where the condition assertion has failed. How `assert` finds the name and line of code that external `assert` function has been called from?

Comment: `assert` is a macro, not a function.

Comment: ...and (typically) uses the `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` standard macros in its expansion.

Comment: C or C++? Pick one. It cannot be both.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` work in C. is it different in C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does so by using macros like `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`, see [here(for gcc)](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html) and [here(vs)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx).

You can view a source file for `assert.h` [here](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/assert_8h_source.html)